# JavaScript Quiz Scoring Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I'm doing this project in javascipt for a website with a quiz, made in Javascript, css, html and jquery, and I've had an issue with getting the scoring to work. The problem is getting a total at the end of the quiz when the results sections is loaded. It just keeps coming up with the same number every time I end the quiz, 1/6. This is what i have got so far:

```
var answers = "0";
function answerTotals()
{

if (document.getElementById("1A").checked = true) answers++;
else(console.log("answer was incorrect"));
}
```

This part displays the results on the page:

```
function showScore()
{

document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = "You Got " +  answers + "/6";
console.log("Score is displayed.");
}
```

And the question:

```
<div id="questions1">
<h1>Question 1.</h1>
<br>
Why are there data types in JavaScript?
<br>
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" id="1A" onchange="question1()">As it helps a computer    differentiate between different data.
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" id="1B" onchange="question1Wrong1()">There aren't.
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" id="1C" onchange="question1Wrong2()">To help it interact with Java.
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="D" id="1D" onchange="question1Wrong3()">To allow it to             complete a task.
<br>
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="nextQuestion();answerTotals()">
<br>
<br>
<p onclick="hint1()">
</div>
```

Comment: Hope it isn't a Javascript quiz! (lighthearted, not actually being mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value to true, not checking for congruency. Try this

```
if (document.getElementById("1A").checked === true) answers++;
```

Comment: why not just `document.getElementById("1A").checked && answers++;`

Comment: I like that syntax too, Todd, but I have been told it is less readable. It requires a deeper understanding of the way javascript interprets each line.  Both ways work